# Magento 2 - Start delta anew with deleting orders, customers directly in the database

Tags: magento-2.1

Is there any way to start the delta process `bin/magento migrate:delta -r --reset` completely anew with truncating the order and the customer tables in the target database before?

Do I have to truncate some tables on the source database as well to make it possible?

Thanks